# Old 43BSD and netstat output

Tags: bsd, netstat

On old 43BSD...

```
netstat -f unix
Active UNIX domain sockets
Address  Type   Recv-Q Send-Q    Inode     Conn     Refs  Nextref Addr
801ca38c dgram       0      0 8008b5c0        0        0        0 /dev/log
801cc10c stream      0      0 8008e690        0        0        0 /dev/printer

Address                 #socket address
type                    #type: stream or dgram
Inode                   #Inode?
Conn                    #sockets connections
Refs                    #?
Nextref                 #?
Addr                    #socket file
```

Anyone know what does it mean "Refs" and "Nextref".
As I know Refs is referred to routing, but in sockets there is no routing as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [netstat/unix.c](https://nic.funet.fi/pub/unix/4.3bsd/net2/usr.bin/netstat/unix.c.Z) those fields are coming from `unp->unp_refs` and `unp->unp_nextref` as defined in [sys/unpcb.h](https://nic.funet.fi/pub/unix/4.3bsd/net2/sys/sys/unpcb.h.Z):

```c
/*
 * A socket may be referenced by a number of sockets (e.g. several
 * sockets may be connected to a datagram socket.)  These sockets
 * are in a linked list starting with unp_refs, linked through
 * unp_nextref and null-terminated.  Note that a socket may be referenced
 * by a number of other sockets and may also reference a socket (not
 * necessarily one which is referencing it).  This generates
 * the need for unp_refs and unp_nextref to be separate fields.
 *\
```

```c
        struct  unpcb *unp_refs;        /* referencing socket linked list */
        struct  unpcb *unp_nextref;     /* link in unp_refs list */
```